# Accompanist WebView not filling its max size at launch and not scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using the accompanist webview for compose, and when loading the url I need, at launch, the webpage adjusts its size to fit in less than half screen. The website that I need to load works well on Google chrome and in other browsers.

Edit: Here's the entire home screen code, where the webview is:

```kotlin
....
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    goToSettingsScreen: () -> Unit,
    viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state

    val preferences = runBlocking { viewModel.userPreferences.first() }

    val webViewState = rememberWebViewState(url = preferences.url)
    //val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    val mContext = LocalContext.current
    //Log.i("prefval", preferences.url)

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CustomTopAppBar(
                toggleMenu = { viewModel.toggleDropdownMenu() },
                isMenuOpen = state.value.isHomeDropdownMenuOpen,
                goToSettingsScreen = {
                    goToSettingsScreen()
                    viewModel.toggleDropdownMenu()
                }
            )
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding())
                //.verticalScroll(scrollState)
        ) {
            WebView(
                state = webViewState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                onCreated = {
                    it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    it.settings.allowFileAccess = true
                    it.fitsSystemWindows = true
                    it.setDownloadListener(
                        object : DownloadListener {
                            override fun onDownloadStart(
                                url: String?,
                                userAgent: String?,
                                contentDisposition: String?,
                                mimetype: String?,
                                contentLength: Long
                            ) {
                                val request: DownloadManager.Request =
                                    DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                                request.apply {
                                    setMimeType(mimetype)
                                    setDescription("Downloading file")
                                    addRequestHeader("UserAgent", userAgent)
                                    setTitle(
                                        URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                            url,
                                            contentDisposition,
                                            mimetype
                                        )
                                    )
                                    setNotificationVisibility(
                                        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
                                    )
                                }
                                val downloadManager = mContext.getSystemService(
                                    Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE
                                ) as DownloadManager?
                                downloadManager?.enqueue(request)
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Downloading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
....
```

Here are some screenshots:

This one shows the app at launch. As you can see it's not fitting the entire screen.

[image]

Here,  I triggered a login error (the yellow box), and the page adjusts its size, but not enough to fill the screen.

[image]

And here I triggered another error message (bigger yellow box), and the page finishes adjusting its size. Also I tried to scroll, in order to see the error message (you can see the scroll bar appearing on the right side of the webview), but nothing happened.

[image]

Before using the accompanist webview, I tried to use the original one. Basically the code is almost the same but the webView is inside the AndroidView composable. I was having the same problems, with the difference that at launch, the webpage fitted the screen, until I tried to add the vertical scroll modifier (I think that this is not needed, but I couldn´t scroll...). It fixed the scroll, but ended up having the same problems I mentioned earlier (the webpage not fitting the entire screen at launch).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using the below code in your AndroidView? The trick is setting **layoutParams**.

```
AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(it).apply {
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
})
```

Comment: Yes. I set the layoutParams to match_parent when I tried to use the WebView. But this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please post the code for the entire screen? Perhaps another component is pushing the webview up?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
WebView(
                        state = webViewState,
                        captureBackPresses = true,
                        layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        ),
                        onCreated = { it: WebView ->
                            it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

                        }
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the srcoll state.

```
WebView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
    state = webViewState,
    captureBackPresses = true,
    onCreated = { it: WebView ->
        it.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
)
```